# How to show error on screen after failling a webservice call on Webform submitForm?

Tags: 8, webforms

I made a custom handler for one of my webform to call a service when the form is submitted. Here is my code. It is working when the service return a response with status code = 200 but I cannot find a way to notify the view when an error is raised by the webservice. I would like to show a modal with an error message but cannot find how to do this.

```
class CRMWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
    try {
      $data = array(
        'firstName' => $webform_submission->getData()['lastname'],
        'lastName' => $webform_submission->getData()['firstname'],
        'civility' => $webform_submission->getData()['civility'],
        'email' => $webform_submission->getData()['email'],
      );
     
      $payload = json_encode($data);
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://my-url.com");
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

      $result = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);

      $json = json_decode($result, TRUE);
      $succeed = is_bool($json) ? $json : FALSE;
      if (!$succeed && curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200) {
        throw new \Exception('No valid response from server.');
      }
    }
    catch (\Exception $exception) {
      \Drupal::messenger()->addError('No valid response from server.');
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `curl_exec()` still returns `FALSE` in case of errors, even when you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `TRUE`. Passing to `json_decode()` a value that isn't a string is probably going to cause an error. Also, once the resource is de-allocated with `curl_close()`, passing that resource to any cURL function doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'll try to improve the code but this does not answer my current issue.

Comment: The code doesn't correctly handle the value returned from `curl_exec()`. This is at least the first part to fix.

Comment: With the current code, I have an exception thrown if the response status code is not 200 (No valid response from server) but still the view show a success message.

Comment: The code shown in the question catches the exception, but the exception is thrown when: The value of `$succeed` is equivalent to the Boolean `FALSE` and the value returned from `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)` is different from 200. Calling `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)` after `curl_close()` doesn't make sense. The exception is caught before it arrives to the view, which thinks nothing wrong happened.

Comment: Also, the question shows the code for a Webform handler. From it to a view the step is too long. There isn't any way for a Webform handler to return something to a view, which could also not be involved.

Comment: I move the `curl_close()` line after the if clause but it does not change anything. Throwing the exception cause an error saying `Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "No valid response from server."`

Comment: So there is no way to notify the view an error happened on the handler ?

Comment: You should check what the Webform module code does and in which way it integrates with the Views module. If there is something the Views module asks to the Webform module, which the Webform module asks to its Webform handlers, then it's possible. Otherwise, no, it's not possible.

Comment: I could not find how to do it in the documentation, hence my question.